# How to include dependency classes in my eclipse(juno) project?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I have kept all my jar files inside `Web-content/WEB-INF/lib` and build into `Java-Resources/Libraries`. My project has been working fine for last 2 weeks, however, suddenly today all the dependencies are throwing `ClassNotFoundException`. Please help.

I also tried keeping all the jars in another folder and adding them using Java *Build Path > libraries*.

Strangely, all the jars are added under **libraries** and everything was working fine till yesterday!!

Edit: I made two copies of the jars in WEB-INF/lib (simple copy-paste), and again added them (the new copy) using Build Path (So, now there are two instances of each). This fixed the problem. 
Any views on why this happened?

Edit 2: My classpath file : (Multiple copy of jar files and the 'dependency' folder were created when I was trying different things to solve my problem)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.7.0_45">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v7.0">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>

    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar"/>

    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13-20150929.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/junit-4.12.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/poi-excelant-3.13-20150929.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/poi-scratchpad-3.13-20150929.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/dependecies/commons-codec-1.9.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/dependecies/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/dependecies/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/dependecies/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/dependecies/jstl-1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/dependecies/junit-4.12.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/dependecies/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/dependecies/poi-excelant-3.13-20150929.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/dependecies/poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/dependecies/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13-20150929.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/dependecies/poi-scratchpad-3.13-20150929.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/dependecies/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/Copy of jstl-1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/poi-3.13-20150929.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/Copy of poi-3.13-20150929.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general to maintain your project it's much more simpler if your are managing your dependencies by additional software.

If you are having problems with your references you should use MAVEN (MVN). Then eclipse will resolve all your dependent JARs and configure your eclipse properly.

If you want to stay with Eclipse, please paste here you .classpath file from your project.

Comment: it looks good, did you try to remove all libs and then add them one more time?

Comment: making copies of previous libs and adding them again worked for me, so replacing the previous libs would have worked fine too! But any thoughts on why this happened suddenly? Does this mean eclipse (without using MAVEN) is unstable?

Comment: Eclipse has always some problems with dependencies :(